# Get the details View from TableView Items in Xcode(iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

Please follow the following code:

**DetailsViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailsViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong , nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *TitleLabel;
@property (strong , nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *DescriptionLabel;
@property (strong , nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ImageView;
@property (strong , nonatomic) NSArray *DetailModal;

@end
```

**TableViewController.m**

```
#import "DetailsViewController.h"

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
 if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {

   DetailsViewController *detailsviewcontroller = [segue destinationViewController];
   NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
   int row = [myIndexPath row];
   NSLog(@"Tanim = %i",row);
   detailsviewcontroller.DetailModal = @[_Title[row],_Description[row], _Images[row]];

}
}
```

I can use the above code and also set the segue identifier "ShowDetails" from my story board but don't goto the detailsViewController window. Can any one help about this issue or suggest me????

Comment: where you are calling your segue

Comment: Actually I have created a table view with few items and want to get the details of these. But can not get detailsViewController window by using above.

Comment: Did you connected segue in your storyboard? If possible add a screenshot of your storyboard which explains how you have connected segue.

Comment: @Naga Mallesh Maddali, I have already connected the segue with my storyboard. When I simply click on the tableview item it works fine but when I add my `detailsviewcontroller.DetailModal = @[_Title[row],_Description[row], _Images[row]];` code . Its don't get the detailsViewController window..

Comment: @User9975 It should work. Are  you seeing any crash? Please check your console.

Comment: Yes. I have found something [like](https://gist.github.com/exclusiveTanim/10d7636023eb50b2ca83).

Comment: I have seen your error. The ViewController in the Storyboard that you linked the segue is not of class DetailViewController I presume. Also check if the Segue name is "ShowDetails"

Comment: As per your error report it looks u had created IBAction method later you deleted or renamed but your ViewController is still holding the reference to the IBAction method, select the view controller and check in connection property if there is any method named setDetailModel and delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen your error. The ViewController in the Storyboard that you linked the segue is not of class DetailViewController I presume. Also check if the Segue name is "ShowDetails"

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `[segue destinationViewController]` is not a `DetailsViewController`. Add a breakpoint just after that line and see the type of `destinationViewController`. It could be a `UINavigationController` or `UITabBarController`. In that case access your destination controller from the their array of `viewcontrollers`.

Comment: Thanks @sleepwalkerfx. I can solved the above issue. Thanks to all